# How do I create a container entity that contains variable number of fields

Tags: nodes, entities

I am interested in creating a content type that contains a variable number of fields. Each field contains an entity reference to another entity, but as I said there may be one field or 4 fields. I'm a little unclear the best way to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want to achieve, but the following two modules come to my mind that could be helpful:

- [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)

> Field collection provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.

- [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group)

> All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.

I suppose in your case *Field Group* would actually be the more interesting module to look at. You can wrap a group of fields and you can then set the number of the field group to `unlimited`.

You can also have groups inside of groups. But things *can* actually get a bit 'messy' when editing a node with grouped groups.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is not a collection of fields as previously answered, but to have an indeterminate number of a single field, that functionality is built into Drupal. At the bottom of the Field edit page, is a section for the Number of Values:

[image]

Here you can set how many fields you want represented in the content. If it is a select list, you will be able to choose multiple items from one list, it will not add a whole new select list for each entry.